# How to create a new process with command line arguments and give the PID to the parent process?

Tags: c++, winapi, process, pid

I'm trying to create a cross platform function for creating a new process using both Unix and Windows.

Using fork() & exec() in Unix is easy enough. Though I'm having trouble figuring it out in Windows. I'm sure you know exec functions don't return the child's pid. In Unix fork would do that. But there is no fork in Windows. So I tried using WinAPI's CreateProcess, but found no straightforward way to add command line arguments.

So I'm a little lost here, if anyone knows a way to create a new process with command line arguments and returning the child's pid to the parent, I would be quite grateful if you would share your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use createprocess() function in windows.

Its signature is below

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  _In_         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  _In_         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  _Out_        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

Example:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; //This structure has process id

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` member has the PID.